# How does autoreleasing work in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory

I am just reading through the [Practical Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW1) guide.

I am somewhat confused by this block of code:

```
- (void)printHello {
    NSString *string;
    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

It seems to me that string is going to have a reference count of 0.  Is this true?

What stops string from being deallocated before we call `NSLog(string)`?

Is this somehow equivalent to this:

```
- (void)printHello {
    NSString *string;
    string = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"] retain] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

---

**Edit**: Similarly this code is given in the [Practical Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW1)
 guide:

```
- (NSString *)fullName {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
    return string;
}
```

When and how does the return value get freed?  Who is the owner?  Does the caller of `fullName` need to release the string returned by full name?

Comment: you don't indicate whether you are referring to iPhone or Mac, there is a difference since Mac has garbage collection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking,

```
- (void)printHello {
    NSString *string;
    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

Is not equivalent to

```
- (void)printHello {
    NSString *string;
    string = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"] retain] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

The convention is that a method should autorelease any object it returns. The only exception (AFAIK) is for constructors, which return an object with a +1 retain count. Since `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` returns an object. In first snippet, `stringWithFormat:` returns an already autoreleased object. the second snippet, you're retaining it once more and it'll be released twice (which has the same effect, but the second retain/autorelease pair is redundant).

Ok, now to answer your question. Essentially, every time UIKit calls your code, it creates an `NSAutoreleasePool` object. Every time you autorelease an object, its added to this pool. Finally, when your code returns back to UIKit, it calls the drain method on the pool (i.e `[pool drain]`) and that releases every object which has been added to the pool and deallocates the pool. Also, autorelease pools can be nested, so you can create your own pools and drain them if you're going to be creating a lot of autoreleased objects. It isn't as complicated as it sounds.

I'd highly recommend that you read the [Autorelease Pools](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI) chapter in the Memory Management Guide (Which incidentally, comes right after the [Practical Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW1) chapter).

Answer (score 8):

First of all:

```
NSLog(string);
```

Don’t do this. (I just realized it comes right from the Apple docs. Weird.) The first argument to `NSLog` is the formatting string. If your `string` contains some percent escapes, bad things will happen. The correct, if slightly longer way is:

```
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

Now to the point: Autoreleased objects do not have zero retain count. They have retain count 1+ and have a pending –1 operation on them that will happen “soon in the future”.

The precise meaning of “soon in the future” depends on the situation. If you’re on the main thread and there is no additional autorelease pool in place, autoreleased objects will be released on the next runloop iteration. This does not have to be the case if you have an additional release pool:

```
// Let’s pretend this is a long loop and you don’t want to wait
// for the autoreleased objects to be collected by the main pool.
for (…) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString *foo = [NSString stringWith…];
    [pool drain];
    // Now foo is no longer valid.
}
```

As for returning autoreleased objects, that’s one of the main use cases for autoreleasing. You are returning an object that will perish “soon”, but if the caller is interested, he can retain and take over the ownership. (It’s like, if you pardon the image, passing a bomb with a burning safety fuse. If the caller is interested, he’ll put out the fuse by retaining.) And if the caller is not interested, like maybe he’s ignoring an output from a function or just uses the value to construct some other object, he does not do anything and the object will get out of memory:

```
- (id) createObject {
    return [NSString stringWith…];
}

- (void) interestedCaller {
    NSString *value = [[self createObject] retain];
}

- (void) notInterestedCaller {
    [self createObject]; // maybe just interested in side effects
    NSString *differentString = [NSString stringWithString:[self createObject]];
}
```

This is really convenient and makes the manual memory management quite pleasant. You might be interested in [run loops](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) and the [Objective-C tutorial by Scott Stevenson](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/).

Comment: In fact, that code was taken from Apple's own documentation. I complained to them about NSLog. You should, too.

Comment: i think one should also - since there was no mention of iPhone - be a bit careful here, when there is a garbage collector it can happen that objects are released in other contexts as well.